# the correct way to use options from settings page

Tags: plugin-development, options

I'm creating a plugin in Wordpress and am a little confused how I should use settings I set in my settings page.

I used: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages to create my settings page. All fine, it's saving the options into the options table. I can echo them out but the only way I can get it to do it is with:

```
$value = get_option('my_option_name')['my_option']; 
echo $value;
```

This doesn't seem a very nice way of doing it to me, and Netbeans gives me a red line under the code saying it's not compatible with my version of PHP, it works but this surely isn't the way I'm supposed to echo out values from my settings page is it?

Comment: This is more a "which PHP version to support?" type of question. While in later/more current versions (5.4+) this is fully valid, it will brake in older ones. Like `$foo = [];` vs. `$foo = array();`. Please read about that on php.net or [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_option( $option )` returns an array. You need to get access to that array, and *then* get the keys/values inside of it.

Try this instead:

```
$value = get_option( 'my_option_name' );
echo $value['my_option'];
```